# 2 different background colours?

Tags: html, css

How can I have 2 different background colors, like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwnhG.png

The grid I'm working with is 970px wide. I want a sidebar that's 220 pixels wide (on the left, behind the red) and the main content at 750px (on the right, behind the blue).

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Do you want a *background* with 2 colors, or do you actually want a page layout with a sidebar that you can put content in?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `linear-gradients`

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 30%, orange 30%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red 30%, orange 30%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red 30%, orange 30%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, red 30%, orange 30%);
}
```

```html
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using 2 divs? http://jsfiddle.net/dowpguwv/1/

html:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

css:

```
#left {
float: left;
width: 220px;
background-color: red;
height: 100vh;  
}
#main {
width: 750px;
background-color: blue;
height: 100vh;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example.

```css
.main-box{
width:970px;
background:#1073B9;
height:500px;
}

.side-bar{
width:220px;
background:#FC0018;
height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
    <div class="side-bar"></div>
     
</div>
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Coding_killer/x9f2bth8/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a Grid System (well that's what the Bootstrap framework calls it anyways http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Assuming you want your sidebar and main content in separate divs, you can do the following:

```
.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 220px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;   
    height: 250px;
}
.aside,
.article{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;    
}
.aside{
    width: 220px;
    background: #f00;
}
.article{
    width: 750px;
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="aside"></div>
    <div class="article"></div>
</section>
```